# Is it possible to define a const member with a factory method not defined as const?

Tags: c++, constants, member, factory-pattern

I have a private data member in my header file that is static and I would like for it to be const as well. However when I assign a value to that member in my constructor with a factory method that returns objects of that type I get an error saying that the method is not marked as const. Is there any way I can define my member with const or do I just have to keep it mutable?

Here is the code that I have written:

.h file:

```
class Dealer {

static std::tuple<std::string, std::string,
          std::string, std::string> suits;
```

.cpp file:

```
Dealer::Dealer () {

suits = std::make_tuple (
    "Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs");
```

As it is now the code compiles, but when I try to define the suits tuple with the const keyword this is the error I get:

```
 candidate
  function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const std::tuple<std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string>' (aka
  'const tuple<basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >, basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >,
  basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >, basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > >'), but
  method is not marked const
tuple& operator=(typename conditional<_CanMoveAssign::value, tuple, __nat>::type&& __t)
```

Comment: Why do you make it static, if each constructor "initializes" (assigns to) it? Static member variables needs to be defined in a single translation unit (source file) and can be properly initialized at the definition. That also allows you to initialize `const` variables.

Comment: And if the variable isn't [ODR-used](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use) then you can even initialize `const` static member variables inline in the class definition itself. Or since C++17 use the `inline` keyword for inline definition. See e.g. [this `static` member reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) for more details about `static` members.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think since I used that method the compiler didn’t understand it would always be the same so it wouldn’t allow me to assign the value in the header file. Or maybe I just have a fundamental misunderstanding of what static means. My understanding of static is if the value of that member will be consistent across all instances of that class, then it should be static. In this case the Dealer class will always have the same four suits to be used for creating Card objects.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it makes no sense to declare the member as `static` and then initialize it in the constructor.

> My understanding of static is if the value of that member will be
>   consistent across all instances of that class, then it should be
>   static. In this case the Dealer class will always have the same four
>   suits to be used for creating Card objects.

Your understanding is correct, but then you should not initialize it in the constructor, because then for each instance you create, the member will be initialized again.

Next, it is not clear why you want to use a tuple. Tuples are for inhomogeneous collections of elements (eg a string and an int and a double). For homogeneous collections there is no reason to use tuple. As the number of elements is fixed, you can use a `std::array`. That would be

```
class Dealer {
    // declaration:
    static const std::array<std::string,4> suits;

};

// definition in the source file:
const std::array<std::string,4> Dealer::suits = {"a","b","c","d"};
```

However, to address your error, lets assume the member is not `static`, then this

```
struct foo_broken {
    const int x;
    foo_broken() {
        x = 5;
    }
};
```

will not work. Before the body of the constructor is executed members are initialized. Inside the constructor you cannot initialize, but only assign to them. As `x` is `const` we cannot assign to it. The solution is to use the initializer list as in

```
struct foo {
    const int x;
    foo() : x(5) {}
};
```

You should always prefer the initializer list rather than assignment in the constructor if possible. Otherwise you make an unnecessary assignment (and it fails completely if the member is `const`).

PS: There is too little context to know for sure, but you should consider to use a `enum` instead of strings. Strings are good when you need to print the value on the screen, but for everything else an `enum` is more appropriate.

PPS: There is no "factory method" in your code. That term refers to something rather specific which isn't present here. If you actually do have a factory method, you should include it in the question, though for a static member it is not that relevant whether you create instances via a factory.

Comment: So essentially there should be a line outside of the constructor in the implementation file that specifically assigns the value of a static const member as defined in the header file? I did this and the compiler would not allow me to declare it as static in the implementation file... Why the discrepancy?

Comment: @BrandynG this sound like you have a different question. I cannot say anything without seeing the code. Dont know what discrepancy you mean

Comment: by discrepancy I mean why am I not able to also include the static keyword in the when I assign the value in my implementation file to my static const member that I defined in my header file?

Comment: @BrandynG see my example, you need the `static` on the declaration, not on the definition. Would need to do some research myself to explain more